# Installation issues for Virtualenv and VirtualenvWrapper in 13.04

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, flask, bottle

Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox. I am trying to install VirtualEnv to start learning Flask and bottle.
Some details of my setup.

```
vks@UbSrVb:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.2 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"

vks@UbSrVb:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
vks@UbSrVb:~$ echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
/usr/bin/python
vks@UbSrVb:~$ echo $VIRTUALENV_PYTHON

vks@UbSrVb:~$
```

When I boot my Virtual Machine, I get the following error on my console

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

When i try to initialize a virtualenv I get the following errors

```
vks@UbSrVb:~/dropbox/venv$ virtualenv try1
New python executable in try1/bin/python3.2
Also creating executable in try1/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
    no_pip=options.no_pip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1081, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1499, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system


vks@UbSrVb:~/dropbox/venv$ ls
try1
vks@UbSrVb:~/dropbox/venv$ ls try1/
bin  include  lib
vks@UbSrVb:~/dropbox/venv$
```

My .bashrc entries

```
export WORKON_HOME='~/dropbox/venv/'
source '/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
```

Q1 - As per the error at bootup, How do I ensure *virtualenv* is installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly ?
Q2 - Even with sudo I get the same "Read-only file system" Error ?

*I have tried installing virtualenv using pip and then apt-get, just to hit and try.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trying to install a virtualenv on a mountpoint that does not support [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) . If you look at the output of `mount` you will see has some mountpoint at `/home/yourusername/dropbox`.
Try a different location, such as your home directory:

```
cd 
virtualenv --python=python2.7 flaskenv
```

(note: currently flask only works on python 2)

There is no point syncing the vritualenv on dropbox anyway. It won't work on another system unless its identical. You can sync between virtualenvs using pip [requirements.txt files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) .

Comment: thanks guysoft. I will try this out. And extra thanks for sync tip.

Comment: Ok, seems like you can only run flask on python 2. [According to this issue opened in their github](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/339). You must use `virtualenv --python=python2.7 flaskenv`. Updated the answer to include this.

Comment: Thank you very much GuySoft. I was able to install Flask.

Comment: GuySoft, can you please help here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811586/flask-not-working-in-virtualenv-setup

Comment: Vivek Sharma, No Idea about that. Not that much experience with Flask yet.